# Comparing values in dictionaries in Python and returning a value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, compare

I have the following dictionaries set up in python.

```
Ex1={"Upper_body" : True, "Lower_body" : False, "Core" : False,'routine': "4 x 8 reps arm curl, 4 x 8 reps chest press, 4 x 8 reps shoulder press"}
Ex2={"Upper_body" : True, "Lower_body" : False, "Core" : False,'routine':"4 x 8 reps squats, 4 x 8 reps leg press, 20 x lunges"}
Ex3={"Upper_body" : True, "Lower_body" : False, "Core" : True,'routine':"4 x 8 reps arm curl, 4 x 8 reps chest press, 4 x 8 reps shoulder press, 20 min plank"}
```

I want to ask the client to choose which parts of the body they want to focus there exercise on.  So I have set up the following code to find out what the client wants:

```
def yes_no(question):
answer = input(question).lower()
if answer=='yes':
    ans=True
else:
    ans=False
return(ans)

client = { "Upper_body"  : yes_no("Do you want to exercise the upper body? "),
     "Lower_body" : yes_no("Do you want to exercise the lower body? "),
     "Core" : yes_no("Do you want to exercise the core muscle group? ")}
```

Now I want the program to check the values entered in the client dictionary against the exercise dictionaries and then return / output the routine from the exercise that matches what the client wants.  Can this be done?

Comment: Are these the only exercises that you will have?

Comment: I am hoping to have more exercises potentially 8 but wondering if it is possible to do what I want before I progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put each exercise dictionary in a list and iterate over the list:

```
exercises = [
    {"Upper_body" : True, "Lower_body" : False, "Core" : False,'routine': "4 x 8 reps arm curl, 4 x 8 reps chest press, 4 x 8 reps shoulder press"},
    {"Upper_body" : True, "Lower_body" : False, "Core" : False,'routine':"4 x 8 reps squats, 4 x 8 reps leg press, 20 x lunges"},
    {"Upper_body" : True, "Lower_body" : False, "Core" : True,'routine':"4 x 8 reps arm curl, 4 x 8 reps chest press, 4 x 8 reps shoulder press, 20 min plank"}
             ]

def yes_no(question):
    answer = input(question).lower()
    if answer=='yes':
        ans=True
    else:
        ans=False
    return(ans)


client = { "Upper_body"  : yes_no("Do you want to exercise the upper body? "),
     "Lower_body" : yes_no("Do you want to exercise the lower body? "),
     "Core" : yes_no("Do you want to exercise the core muscle group? ")}


for exercise in exercises:
    if exercise["Upper_body"] == client["Upper_body"] and exercise["Lower_body"] == client["Lower_body"] and exercise["Core"] == client["Core"]:
        print(exercise["routine"])
```